# How to use windows.h header file in C++?

Tags: c++, header

I needed help with using the windows.h header file in C++.
I see people using windows.h in their programs to (obviously) interact with windows, but I don't know how to use it.
Specifically, is there a website that lists and describes the methods and functions in the windows.h header file.
I try to open the windows.g header file and see the methods for myself but I only see a bunch of other #includes and don't know what to do next.
I'm new to C++, so I apologize if my question is not a good one!

Comment: What do you want to do in your application? `windows.h` is the header file for the Windows API, which is ***huge***. Do you want to show a window? Close a file? Play a sound? Open a network connection? The Windows operating system can do quite a bit of stuff. You need to narrow down the scope of your question.

Comment: Normally, you choose what headers to include based on the functionality you want.  You don't choose to use a header based on its name, or because other people are using it.  What functionality are you after?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447209(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I see.  I was specifically trying to rewrite memory by finding addresses of windows applications through cheat engine.

Comment: @Vee: I'm sorry to break this to you but if you're new to C++, you will not be able to learn everything you need to do what you want to do with just this Stack Overflow question. That requires a much higher level knowledge of the engine and how Windows applications work.

Comment: You don't just go and include headers. Read the documentation for Windows API in MSDN. At the end there is always specified what header you need to include and what library to link with.

Comment: @Insilico Ok.  Are there any books you would recommend to help me learn necessary things?  I mean, I just finished Sams Teach Yourself C++ so I am unsure of what to read next.

Comment: @Vee - Including windows.h gives you access to **all** Windows APIs. That's hundreds of thousand of lines of declarations.  You need about 10 books to cover all of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there's the Microsoft Developer Network at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/ which have reference and, I think, beginner tutorials, but you'll probably be better off with a book.   Charles Petzold's "Programming Windows" used to use C++ (though I believe recent editions use C#)